# Removing repetitive code in ASP.NET MVC Controller actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to keep things DRY, so I'm trying to figure out: Is it possible to remove repetitive parameters and code from ASP.NET MVC Controller actions?  eg given these Actions:

```
public ActionResult List(string key, string signature) { GetSignature(key); // etc } 
public ActionResult Add(string key, string signature) { GetSignature(key); // etc } 
public ActionResult Update(string key, int id, string signature) { GetSignature(key, id.ToString()); // etc} 
public ActionResult Delete(string key, int id, string signature) { GetSignature(key, id.ToString()); // etc} 
public ActionResult Action1(string key, string x, string y, string z, string signature) { GetSignature(key, x, y, z);//etc}
```

Is there any way to refactor out the repetitive `key` and `signature` parameters, and the call to `GetSignature()`?

There are two obstacles to refactoring I can think of:

1. It's MVC so the Actions are the first port of call - it may not be possible to have a refactored method that is called before the Action.
2. The GetSignature() method is called using all of the Action's parameters, so it may be difficult to refactor.

Answer (score 3):

I like the direction Scott started but would recommend to take it another layer down so that the GenerateSignature method does not have to do discovery with the thing object (Do I have an Id or do I have string X/Y/Z or do I only have Key/Signature, etc).

```
public class MySignatureCreateRead
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Signature { get; set; }
}

public class MySignatureUpdateDelete : MySignatureCreateRead
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MySignatureAction : MySignatureCreateRead
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
    public string Z { get; set; }
}
```

Which puts the ActionResults like:

```
public ActionResult List(MySignatureCreateRead signature) { GetSignature(signature); /* etc */ }
public ActionResult Add(MySignatureCreateRead signature) { GetSignature(signature); /* etc */ }
public ActionResult Update(MySignatureUpdateDelete signature) { GetSignature(signature); /* etc */ }
public ActionResult Delete(MySignatureUpdateDelete signature) { GetSignature(signature); /* etc */ }
public ActionResult Action1(MySignatureAction signature) { GetSignature(signature); /* etc */ }
```

This also gives you objects to strongly bind views to.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, my suggestion would be to encapsulate your properties in a class:

```
public class MySignatureThing
{
  public string Key {get;set;}
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Signature {get;set;}
  public string X {get;set;}
  public string Y {get;set;}
  public string Z {get;set;}
}
```

Then your action methods change to this:

```
public void Add(MySignatureThing thing) { GenerateSignature(thing); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a factory to create ActionResults, and make the key and signature members of the factory.  Unless you are reusing the same key and signature a lot of the time, it's likely to look like:

```
myList = new ActionResultsFactory(key, signature).List();
```

Which hardly seems better than

```
myList = new List(key, signature);
```

but maybe it has value in some situations.